# how to read doc file in android application

Tags: android

I have an application and there is a requiremt to read a doc/dox file without using any third party tool like apache poi or any other.Can You plz tell Me how is this possible.
Thanx in advance.

Comment: How to increase accpet rate..????

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think there is native support for programmatically reading doc/docx files from android. You can use an opensource library like jOpenDocument made exactly for this purpose.

http://www.jopendocument.org/